# Flutter Error: Unable to Load my audio asset

Tags: flutter

When I run my project, It's shows me the following message:

```
< Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: assets/audio/1.mp3>
```

This is my code:

```
FlatButton(
    onPressed: (){
        //final player = AudioCache();
        player.play("audio/1.mp3");
        //player.clear("1.mp3");
    },
    child: Image.asset("images/number-1.png", height: 60, width: 60,),
)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you added your files to `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Comment: @don-prog yes already added

Comment: @sagaracharya no :(